# How can I get the next hour relative to the specified date?

Tags: linux, shell

I  use the  command to get next day relative to specified date as follows:

```
date -d "20130107 1days" "+%Y%m%d"
```

but , if the input is 2013010712 , I want to get 2013010711 , how can i do ?

Or, If there is a simple method to do it?

Comment: That would be the previous hour?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz the previous hour or the next hour, It does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My date isn't new enough to handle the 2013010712 format but, with some helper punctuation added for my `date` (GNU coreutils 8.13), the method for changing hours is shown:

```
$ date -d "2013-01-07 12 -1hour" "+%Y%m%d%H"
2013010711
$ date -d "2013-01-07 12 +1hour" "+%Y%m%d%H"
2013010713
```